# Regex to replace (void)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace the word `(void)` (parenthesis included) with an empty string `""` in `C#`.  I have tried the following expressions but none are working.

- `@"\b(void)\b"`
- `@"\b((void))\b"`
- `@"(void)"`

The first two completely remove the word `void` but the parenthesis remain, whilst the other doesn't work.
I've also tried `@"\b(+\w+)"`  which is not working as well.

Comment: the `(` and `)` denote captures, so are special constructs. to capture them explicitly, escape them in the regex like `\(` and `\)`. `\(void\)` should do what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis, otherwise it will be treated as a capture group

```
\(void\)
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/HOD17l)

Answer (score 2):

Though *Regular Expression* can indeed do this, it is quite a bit of overkill.  You could accomplish it by simply doing:

```
var input = "What (void) happened?";    
var example = Regex.Replace(input, @"\(void\)", "");
```

You could easily do the same code as:

```
var input = "What (void) happened?";
var example = input.Replace("(void)", " ");
```

Both examples working on a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tyZKBc). Keep in mind the second example doesn't use a *Regular Expression* which will yield more performance than the initial example above.

**Update:**
Realized that the `()` were included, you'll need to escape the parenthesis with a backslash `\` to properly remove with the *Regular Expression*.  The `String.Replace` though doesn't need to escape the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [regex recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html#balanced), like this:

(([^()]|(?R))*)